# how to change sybase sql default port

Tags: sybase

Is there any option to change the sybase sql default port ?

Here I want to change the port number because we can't start two SAP instances at the same time on the same server?

Comment: You should probably include more details in your question, such as DB product (Saying it's a Sybase database does not narrow down options), OS, etc...But since you are talking about running SAP..I'll assume you mean Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase ASE retrieves port numbers for the listeners from the `interfaces` file. On *nix systems, this is typically in the Sybase Home directory ($SYBASE/interfaces)

On Windows systems it's called `interfaces.ini` and can be found in %SYBASE%, which is likely to be c:\sybase (I think..been a while since I've run on Windows).

I believe you can launch the GUI interfaces editor through Sybase Central, if you are using that to manage your ASE databases.  `dsedit` and `dscp` are the two utilities that can be used to edit the interfaces file.

You can also manually edit the interfaces file using a text editor such as `vi` but be sure to pay attention to the format of the entries and permissions, so as not to accidentally muck it up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michael's answer:

- ASE interfaces file on Windows is `sql.ini` located in `%SYBASE%\ini` folder.
- ASE on start-up picks up the port number for the `master` entry in the interfaces file